# Hexadecimal - What encoding?

Tags: ios, encoding, hex

I have the following hex:

```
1002d903 864793dd 00000000 00000000
```

What is the encoding of this hex that I need to use to translate it into an IP address?

UTF-8 doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well what IP address is that *meant* to represent? And is it an IPv6 address or IPv4?

Comment: I think its an ipv4 since there are 4 hex blocks like: 134.71.146.49 is  <3133342e 37312e31 34362e34 39>. Off hand, it should be an ipv4. But it might be an ipv6, small posibility.

Comment: It looks a LOT more like an [IPv6 address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ipv6_address_leading_zeros.svg).

Comment: @user1392515: There's rather a lot of data for an IPv4 address. IPv6 looks more likely to me.

Comment: oh ok. my bad. whats the address then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an IP address at all, it will have to be an IPv6 address; that needs 16 bytes. Probably it should be be `1002:d903:8647:93dd:0000:0000:0000:0000`, which can be abbreviated to `1002:d903:8647:93dd::`.

It is possible that the source you got those hex digits from is not displaying raw hex *bytes*, but little-endian 32-bit *words*, in which case it the IP address represented would be `03d9:0210:dd93:4786::`.

However, neither of these possibilities is actually in an allocated part of the IPv6 address space. The `03d9` one would belong to the "truncated NSAPA" space defined by RFC-1888, but that was deprecated in 2004 and never seems to have been used in practice.

How sure are you that the hex string you have encodes an IP address of any kind? What makes you sure of that?

Comment: hmm... well the true answer is its a ipv4: "1002d903 864793dd 00000000 00000000" goes to "864793dd" which goes to "86 47 93 dd" which goes to "134.71.147.221" directly from hex to decimal.  The origins of the hexdump is some udp stuff... that part is part of the original IP header and is the ascii hex dump

Comment: any idea why there are zeros surrounding it and the first hex grouping there? this is all really strange... im using a framework for objective-c, GCDAsyncUDPSocket, long story lol

Comment: As long as you won't reveal _exactly_ what gave you that sequence of hex digits, and in which context, nobody will be able to tell you what the extraneous ones are for. (But one guess could be that 1002d903 is the address of the other end of the UDP connection).

Comment: Well the framework is supposed to pass the source address as an NSData object (binary) to a callback i'm implementing. This is an internal LAN only udp bcast. Depending on what it feels like, it passes either <1002d903 864793dd 00000000 00000000> or <1c1ed903 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000ffff 864793dd 00000000> (it receives the same packet twice).